# Issue on parsing string at JSON.parse

Tags: ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-3

In controller side i am getting params like

```
"{\"violation_date\":\"sdfsdf\",\"violation_time\":\"\"},{\"violation_date\":\"sdfdsf\",\"violation_time\":\"sdfsdf\"},{\"violation_date\":\"1233\",\"violation_
time\":\"\"},{\"violation_date\":\"test\",\"violation_time\":\"time\"}"
```

class of this is `String`. I am trying to parse this. Through

```
JSON.parse(params_gotton)
```

Got

```
 JSON::ParserError (757: unexpected token at ',{"violation_date":"sdfdsf","violation_time":"sdfsdf"},{"violation_date":"1233","violation_time":""},{"violation_d
te":"test","violation_time":"time"}'):
```

What i am doing wrong here. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not valid json, this will work (use []):

```
require 'json'
jsn = '[{"violation_date":"sdfsdf","violation_time":""},
{"violation_date":"sdfdsf","violation_time":"sdfsdf"},
{"violation_date":"1233","violation_time":""},
{"violation_date":"test","violation_time":"time"}]'

JSON.parse(jsn) # => [{"violation_date"=>"sdfsdf", "violation_time"=>""}, {"violation_date"=>"sdfdsf", "violation_time"=>"sdfsdf"}, {"violation_date"=>"1233", "violation_time"=>""}, {"violation_date"=>"test", "violation_time"=>"time"}]
```

To verify json string you could use: http://www.jslint.com/.
And basic json structure: http://json.org/

UPDATED

In your case just try this:

```
JSON.parse('[' + params_gotton + ']')
```

Comment: Mind blowing!! what the thing turned you on to think this way..I was keep trying some rubbish things in my editor.. :(

Comment: I know if inside array this will work. But there is no array in my param. Then how can i parse. My param is "{\"violation_date\":\"sdfsdf\",\"violation_time\":\"\"},{\"violation_date\":\"sdfdsf\",\"violation_time\":\"sdfsdf\"},{\"violation_date\":\"1233\",\"violation_
time\":\"\"},{\"violation_date\":\"test\",\"violation_time\":\"time\"}"

Comment: So add [ and ] to the beginning and end of the string of parameters. '[' + params_gotton + ']' should work

Comment: I tried to add through params_gotton.gsub(params_gotton.chars.first,'[{').gsub(params_gotton[-1,1],'}]') but i got response as "[{\"violation_date\":\"sdfsdf\",\"violation_time\":\"\"}],[{\"violation_date\":\"sdfdsf\",\"violation_time\":\"sdfsdf\"}],[{\"violation_date\":\"1233\",\"viola
tion_time\":\"\"}],[{\"violation_date\":\"test\",\"violation_time\":\"time\"}]" This is also not working

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr.Yevgeniy Anfilofyev. I spent more time to parse this. Thank u so much.

Answer (score 0):

well, received string does not contain a proper Json structure..

First convert that received param in a proper json structure and then parse it using "JSON.parse(params_gotton)".

In above received data all key and value shud be in a key value pair string format.. remove "\" symbol from received data..

it will definitely work fine..